# Confused about strange import behavior within plpython stored procedures

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, plpython

I'm running Postgresql 9.4, and I'm confused about how it handles plpython imports, specifically regarding Decimal.

First example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION devel.foo()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
def myfoo():
    eval("Decimal('40.0')")

myfoo()
plpy.notice("done")
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION devel.foo()
  OWNER TO postgres;

SELECT devel.foo();
```

Result:

> ERROR:  NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined

A little surprising since one of the changes in Postgresql 9.4 is that it's supposed to use Decimal implicitly instead of float within plpython. But OK fine, let's add the import:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION devel.foo()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
from decimal import Decimal

def myfoo():
    eval("Decimal('40.0')");

myfoo()
plpy.notice("done")
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION devel.foo()
  OWNER TO postgres;

select devel.foo()
```

Again:

> ERROR:  NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined

Now let's try placing the import inside the function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION devel.foo()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
def myfoo():
    from decimal import Decimal
    eval("Decimal('40.0')")

myfoo()
plpy.notice("done")
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION devel.foo()
  OWNER TO postgres;


select devel.foo();
```

Result: `devel.foo()` now executes without problems, printing 'done'. Another curious thing: the following also works:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION devel.foo()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
from decimal import Decimal
def myfoo():
    var = Decimal('40.0')
    eval("Decimal('40.0')")

myfoo()
plpy.notice("done")
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION devel.foo()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Questions: why isn't the top level import seen inside `myfoo()`? Why does it suddenly works if I use Decimal within the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is python behavior as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).  The plpythonu execution environment is not global.

> Note, eval() does not have access to the nested scopes (non-locals) in
> the enclosing environment.

Try this code in python (outside of PostgreSQL):

```
def bar():
    from decimal import Decimal
    def foo():
        return eval("Decimal('40.0')")

    return foo()

print(bar())
```

It fails with `NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined`.

Putting `Decimal` into your globals with `global` works:

```
def bar():
    from decimal import Decimal
    global Decimal
    def foo():
        return eval("Decimal('40.0')")

    return foo()

print(bar())
```